# Permission denied, public key (GIT push)

Tags: windows, git, github, public-key

I am very new to coding, I have actually just started learning how to through the use of video tutorials. Anyway one of the steps along the path of learning is setting up an account on GIT and linking this account to my ruby command prompt, where all the work I do is saved onto this app.

The problem I have run into is that, for some reason, after following the instructions of both GIT and the video tutorial I am not quite able to do the following step.

git push -u origin master

the error I get is:
warning: Permanently added to the RSA host key for IP address ..... 
Permission denied (publickey).

My best guess is there is an issue with being an administrator or something along those lines but I do not possess the knowledge to change that at the moment.

I would like to point out here that I am a windows user, I have seen a lot of "solutions" out there which simply dont work for me as they include commands like "sudo" or others which do not exist in the windows format, well at least not on mine as I have decided not to go through Cygwin.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance to who ever tries to help!

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/a/42540

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your SSH public key. Somehow the git server is not able to recognize you and refuse to accept the code you pushed.

SSH keys are stored in `~/.ssh/`. You should make sure there's one created. If there's one, then link it with your git server account, otherwise, create one and link it.

Checkout this tutorial on creating SSH keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows

Comment: Thnx for getting back to me, the problem is this advice you gave me like 99.9% of the advice with regards to coding I have found so far is based on me operating from a mac or linux style programming system. The commands that are given dont work when I type them in. Unless I am doing something wrong which could also be the case. I do believe you are right tho and that my SHH keys are wrong and need to be changed..any idea on how this is done in windows?

Comment: I don't see how what I gave you doesn't work on Windows... To be fair, I don't think I gave you any command. I linked you to the Github help page with details on setting up the SSH key; and on this page, there's 3 choices: "Mac - Windows - Linux", select windows to get windows command.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize what it meant to open Git bash, so whenever I see the $ sign in the code, I assume that it was made for mac or linux, but I think I got it now bud. Thank you for your help.